# Parameterized Constructor with user input (C++)

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that is asking the user to develop 2 types of questions: true/false or multiple choice. 
I have written the classes QuestionTF and QuestionMC - these two classes are derived from their base class Question. 
I have implemented parameters for both TF and MC:

```
QuestionTF(string theQuestion, int pointValue, string theAnswer)
        : Question(theQuestion, pointValue)
```

AND

```
QuestionMC(string theQuestion, int pointValue, string theAnswer)
        : Question(theQuestion, pointValue)
```

When I call the constructor in main - it will look like 
QuestionTF(string, value, string).
How would I code the constructors parameters so that the user has the ability to ask the question, input the value and select their answer (all of which will be set up in an if statement asking the user which type of question he/she would like to set up)?

Example:
QuestionTF("question", 0, "answer");

Comment: Your question is unclear. Define "set the constructor".

Comment: fixed as best as i can explain

Comment: If you're asking how to prompt for these values, the answer is the same as prompting for any kind of input: write the prompt, for each one, to std::cout, use std::getline() to read the next line from std::cin, and then parse it. Once you have all three parameters, construct the object.

Comment: ah, thank you! I thought I needed to set the parameters FIRST and then ask for the input (cin). Thank you for the assistance!!

Comment: @BrittanyFerence I have added the answer, Kindly have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer. I have passed 6 parameters in constructor among them, 3 are for the incorrect options. similarly, you can implement this logic for true and false as well.

```
class question{
public:
question(string question, int pointValue, string opt1,string opt2, string opt3, string opt4){
    int userinput;
    cout<<"Your question is :"<<endl<<question;
    cout<<endl<<"1. "+opt1<<endl<<"2. "+opt2<<endl<<"3. "+opt3<<endl<<"4. "+opt4<<endl;
    cin>>userinput;
    if (userinput== pointValue) {
        cout<<endl<<"Your answer is correct";
    }
    else
        cout<<endl<<"Your answer is incorrect";
}
question(string question, int pointValue){
    int userinput;
    cout<<"Your question is :"<<endl<<question<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"1. True"<<endl<<"2. False"<<endl;
    cin>>userinput;
    if (userinput == pointValue) {
        cout<<"Your answer is correct";
    }
    else
        cout<<"Your answer is incorrect";
}

};

int main(){
question q = question("What is Capital of India ?",1,"Delhi","kolkata","Mumbai","Chennai");
}
```

Comment: Use const & on all those strings, and you reduce overhead in parameter passing by O(length of string).

Comment: @WillBriggs , can you please elaborate on that point. Or pls ,make necessary changes in my code.

Comment: @M.S.P your answer is perfect, however I have to follow a homework assignment and that is out of scope

Comment: @M.S.P Let me give you the the constructor from the parent/child classes 

There are 3 classes:
Question (string question, int value)   - BASE
QuestionTF(string question, int value, string answer) - CHILD
QuestionMC(string question, int value, string answer)  - CHILD

Now, when I call the constructor in MAIN it will require the parameters (as listed above) So your answer is perfect and that would be how I did this as well but it does not meet the requirements
The problem I am running into is : what do I put in the parameters when I call the constructor in MAIN?

Comment: MSP, here's what I mean, as an example:  `question(const string& question, int pointValue, const string& opt1,const string& opt2, const string& opt3, const string& opt4);`.  See this page, scrolling down to the header on passing by const reference: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/